# How to get the return of an exchange parameter with Sap Connector

Tags: .net, vb.net, saprfc, sap-dotnet-connector

I have an issue in reading the return-value of an exchange-parameter.
I am experienced in passing and reading out tables and simple fields, but I don't get this return value.

The image shows the result ("Ergebnis" = Result).
It is a custom RFCs.

[image: Result in SE37]

This is the code. The sap-connector is kind of "wrapped". After executing the RFC I want to read out the exchange-value, but it returns "0" instead of "150".

```
            rfcFunction = connector.CreateFunction("Z_SOME_CUSTOM_RFC")
            With rfcFunction
                .SetValue("I_WERKS", "4711")
                .SetValue("I_MATNR", "1234")
                .SetValue("I_CHARG", "")
            End With
            connector.Execute(rfcFunction) ' This wrapper actually calls the invoke-function
            Return rfcFunction.GetDecimal("E_ZQM_QTY_FULL_UNIT")
```

What is going wrong?

Comment: what kind of object is "connector"? The RfcDestination class from SAP NCo doesn't have either CreateFunction (that is in RfcRepository) or Execute (RfcDestination calls functions using Invoke(), as vwegert mentioned in his answer). Is this some kind of wrapper?

Comment: Yes i have kind of a wrapper and "execute" calls the invoke function

Comment: Then please add the complete code of the wrapper as well. How do you expect us to help you with a problem if you only show half of the code involved?

Comment: The guy who worked with sapconnector and exchange-parameters doesn't need the rest of the code. Anyone who is not experienced with sapconnector can't help at this point. Sorry.

Comment: First check if the function is actually executed in your wrapper. Without looking at it, we can't see if there is a sidecase where the invocation wouldn't be executed or where an exeption may be caught and ignored. Is E_ZQM_QTY_FULL_UNIT a decimal type?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried rfcFunction.GetDecimal("Ergebnis")?

Comment: What result does rfcFunction.GetValue(0) gives you?

Comment: Once but with a very simple example. But even in your screenshot the E_ZQM_QTY_FULL_UNIT has the value 0. So you need somehow to get the result of the function.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the .NET Connector, try to use

```
rfcFunction.Invoke(someDestination)
```

instead of `connector.Execute(rfcFunction)`,

Comment: I am using invoke. It is called in the "execute"-function. It is a wrapper for the connector. I edited in my question. So this won't help.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem is with material number (I_MATNR). When you're testing your function with `SE37` transaction, SAP will automatically call `CONVERSION_EXIT` registered on `MATNR`'s domain.

In my system, material `1234` is converted to `000000000000001234`. But when you call your function using RFC, you need to convert it by yourself, either on client (.Net) or server (ABAP). Try calling your function again using `000000000000001234` as your `I_MATNR` parameter.

Also, if you're working with more complex functions call using RFC, I would like to introduce you to [SharpSapRfc](https://github.com/goenning/SharpSapRfc), an OSS wrapper around NCo 3 that I've been using for some time.

It comes in handy when dealing with Tables and Structures as it maps to Classes and Lists automatically. There are some examples (all using C#) in the repository.

```
using (SapRfcConnection conn = new PlainSapRfcConnection("your-sap-con"))
{
    var result = conn.ExecuteFunction("Z_SOME_CUSTOM_RFC", new {
        I_WERKS = "4711",
        I_MATNR = "1234".
        I_CHARG = ""
    });

    decimal result = result.GetOutput<decimal>("E_ZQM_QTY_FULL_UNIT");
}
```